# JSON Serialization song information

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

I've been able to serialize dictionary before but am not sure how to go about serializing multiple pieces of data.

I want to serialize song information, how would I go about doing this for multiple songs?  The code I have to output the strings are:

```
NSArray *songs = [playlist items];              
  for (MPMediaItem *song in songs){

       NSString *title =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
       NSString *artist =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist];
       NSString *album =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
       NSString *length =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
       NSLog(@"Title: %@\nArtist: %@\nAlbum: %@\nLength: %@",title,artist,album,length);

}
```

I don't know how to separate this in the JSON for every song.

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  It takes about 10 minutes to learn.  Then translating to/from Objective-C arrays and dictionaries is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every `MPMediaItem`, create an `NSDictionary` with key/value pairings equivalent to `title`, `artist`, etc. Then add each one to a mutable array. Finally, serialize the array to JSON. For example:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableSongsToSerialize = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *songs = [playlist items];              
for (MPMediaItem *song in songs){
       NSString *title =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
       NSString *artist =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist];
       NSString *album =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
       NSString *length =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
       NSDictionary *songDictionary = @{@"title": title, @"artist": artist, @"album":album, @"length":length};
       [mutableSongsToSerialize addObject:songDictionary];
}

NSData *jsonRepresentation = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mutableSongsToSerialize options:0 error:NULL];
```

Comment: An array of dictionaries...wow it was that simple.  I was vastly overthinking it.  thank you